# TCL: While no key is pressed loop

Tags: while-loop, tcl, stdin, exit, break

I would like to run a `while` loop until the `stdin` is filled with a character.

```
puts "Press x + <enter> to stop."
while {[gets stdin] != "x"} {
   puts "lalal"
}
```

The problem with the code above that it will wait for `stdin` and I don't want it to wait. I want the code to be executed all the time.

#### Edit 8th September 2011 - 8.55am

The code is used inside a FPGA tool called System Console (Altera). This does work with TCL Commands, but unfortunately I don't know which it can handle and which it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a fileevent on stdin to set a function to be called once the channel becomes readable then use vwait to run the event loop. Your other tasks can be launched using after chains to have work done in pieces without halting the event processing for too long.

```
proc do_work {args} {...}
proc onRead {chan} {
    set data [read $chan]
    if {[eof $chan]} {
        fileevent $chan readable {}
        set ::forever eof
    }
    ... do something with the data ...
}
after idle [list do_work $arg1]
fconfigure stdin -blocking 0 -buffering line
fileevent stdin readable [list onRead stdin]
vwait forever
```

Comment: The problem with the code above is that I can use it. I want to use it inside Altera System Console which doesn't accept `fileevent`. Is there maybe another option? Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @patrick, try to put all your requirements/restrictions in your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the `stdin` channel into non-block mode, the `gets stdin` will return the empty string (and `fblocked stdin` will then be able to return `1`) when input is not available, instead of waiting for something to happen.

```
# Enable magic mode!
fconfigure stdin -blocking 0

puts "Press x + <enter> to stop."
while {[gets stdin] != "x"} {
   puts "lalal"
   after 20;           # Slow the loop down!
}

# Set it back to normal
fconfigure stdin -blocking 1
```

In fact, you can also use the system `stty` program to do [even more fancy things](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14693).

Comment: Note that the above doesn't even touch the event loop. (That's a more elegant way to do it, of course, but can be more intrusive and doesn't seem to be what patrick wants.)